# The grouping and the largest number in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, grouping

Good afternoon!
I started studying MySql and faced with a problem:

> Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT
>   list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'test.product.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in
>   GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I used this site to study https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xxV16kmnZKmPktUdMSK6xZ/0

My task is to make: 
**find a region with the lowest price for each product. When there are multiple regions with the same price, choose the first one in the alphabetical order.**

My table:

```
create table product(id int, name varchar(99));
create table region(id int, name varchar(99));
create table price(productId int, regionId int, price decimal(9, 2));

insert into product values(1, 'Crab');
insert into product values(2, 'Crayfish');

insert into region values(1, 'Kiev');
insert into region values(2, 'Kharkov');
insert into region values(3, 'Lvov');

insert into price values(1, 1, 100);
insert into price values(1, 2, 100);
insert into price values(1, 3, 200);
insert into price values(2, 1, 200);
insert into price values(2, 2, 100);
insert into price values(2, 3, 100);
```

My select :

```
select product.name 'product', price.price, region.name 'Region name' 
from price
left join product on product.id = price.productId
left join region on region.id = price.regionId
where price.price != 0
group by region.name
having max(price.price)
order by region.name
```

Expected result:

```
product region  price
Crab    Kharkov 100
Crayfish    Kharkov 100
```

Comment: mySQL != sql server, please don't tag products not involved

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? You tagged with MySql and sql server but your fiddle is in SQLite. These are all three different.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry, it's error site. I using MySql

Comment: There is one standard ANSI SQL language, but there are many SQL database implementations, and **ALL** of these have some non-standard syntax or language extensions. SQL code from database type to database type is only about 85% compatible. You need to be aware of what kind of database you're actually using.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Ok

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you, I'm using MySql

Comment: You're getting that error because you projected some fields in your SELECT statement that were not used in any aggregation.  To get your query to work as-written, You need to add `product.name`, `price.price` to your GROUP BY.  Your query will still need tweaking after that.

Comment: @ravioli Thank you, everything began to work. But I also got extra fields, how can I remove them?
Should be the first two  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xxV16kmnZKmPktUdMSK6xZ/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like that:

```
select
  p2.name as product,
  (
    select min(r.name)
    from
      price as c2
      inner join region as r on c2.regionid = r.id
    where c2.productId = t.id and c2.price = t.price) as region,
  t.price
from
  product as p2
  inner join (
    select
      p.id,
      min(c.price) as price
    from
      product as p
      left outer join price as c on p.id = c.productId
    group by p.id) as t on p2.id = t.id
```

the main idea is to get minimal prices for every product (sub-query t) and then find minimal (ie first alphabetically) region for every product/price combination

Comment: Thank you very much helped!

Answer (score 0):

To get the lowest price for each products, you can do:

```
select p.*
from price p
where p.price = (select min(p2.price) from price p2 where p2.product_id = p.product_id);
```

Additional `join`s will bring in the names rather than the `id`s.

To get one row per product:

```
select p.product_id, p.price, min(r.name)
from price p join
     region r
     on p.regionId = r.id
where p.price = (select min(p2.price) from price p2 where p2.product_id = p.product_id)
group by p.product_id, p.price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join on the max price grouped  by product and region

```
select t.product, price.price, t.region
from price
INNER JOIN ( 
select price.productID, price.regionId, product.name product, 
          max(price.price) max_price, region.name Region 
from price
left join product on product.id = price.productId
left join region on region.id = price.regionId
where price.price != 0
group by product.name , 
    region.name,
    price.productID,
    price.regionId ) t on t.productId = price.productId  
      and t.regionId = price.regionId and t.max_price =  price.price
```

Comment: Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 't.product.id' in 'on clause

Comment: Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.price.productId' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: answer  update  with all the column not in aggregation function  in group by